# Fixed route on a param is not rendering the assigned component

Tags: react-router, parameters

Here is the router setup

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
   <Route path="/pages(/:section)" component={ Pages }>
     <Route path="/pages/category" component={ Pages.Category }/>
     <Route path="/pages/editor(/:uid)" component={ Pages.Editor }/>
   </Route>
 </Route>
```

The `Pages` component contain `Menu` Component which need to activate a button depend on the `section`. The strange thing here is the component `Pages.Category` is not passed down in `props.children` in the `Pages` so it isn't rendered at all. As soon as I remove `(/:section)` from `path="/pages(/:section)"` the `Pages.Category is rendered as expected. Same for the editor route. Is this expected behaviour? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your code is confusing. If you are nesting routes, there is no need to specify `pages` in the nested route path again. Pages.Category will not be rendered unless path matches `pages/section/pages/category`. Also I don't think it's a good idea to nest under a route with optional path

Comment: I believe you are wrong. You can set absolute path anywhere in your nested routes. This works fine.

Comment: I didn't say your code wouldn't work. I meant that it is difficult to reason about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, from my experience this is expected behavior.

Your `<Route path="/pages(/:section)" component={ Pages }>` is a route group. You can only define the base URL. Right now your router matches this route and displays the 'Pages' components. It displays the first match, and this is the first match. Your code should look something like this to have the groups working :

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
   <Route path="pages" component={ Pages }>
     <Route path="category" component={ Pages.Category }/>
     <Route path="editor(/:uid)" component={ Pages.Editor }/>
   </Route>
 </Route>
```

You can't build a URL on top of a absolute one :

> If a route uses a relative path, it builds upon the accumulated path of its ancestors. Nested routes may opt-out of this behavior by using an absolute path.

Now you can't directly access which page you are on in the 'Pages' component but you can read the current complete path from `this.props.location.pathname`. With a little bit of regex, you can find the current displayed component :

```
this.props.location.pathname.match(/([a-z0-9]+)/g)[1]
// Will give 'category' or 'editor'
```

I have a working exemple on CodePen: http://codepen.io/loico/pen/VjqKvg#/pages/category